# Time efficient Partial Inverted Index building

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to build a partial [`Inverted Index`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). Something like:

```
l = {{x, {h, a, b, c}}, {y, {c, d, e}}}
iI[l]
(*
-> {{a, {x}}, {b, {x}}, {c, {x, y}}, {d, {y}}, {e, {y}}, {h, {x}}}
*)
```

I think it is pretty clear what it does. In the input list, the {x, y ...} are unique, while the {a, b, c, ..} are not.  The output ought to be ordered by `#[[1]]`.

Right now, I am doing this:

```
iI[list_List] := {#, list[[Position[list, #][[All, 1]]]][[All, 1]]} & /@ 
                     (Union@Flatten@Last@Transpose@list)
```

But it looks too convoluted for such an easy task, seems too slow, and I should be able to cope with Legion.

A test drive to compare your results:

```
words = DictionaryLookup[];
abWords = DictionaryLookup["ab" ~~ ___];
l = {#, RandomChoice[abWords, RandomInteger[{1, 30}]]} & /@ words[[1 ;; 3000]];
First@Timing@iI[l]
(*
-> 5.312
*)
```

So, any ideas for an speedup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems a classic task for `Reap`-`Sow`  (improvement in the final version due to @Heike):

```
iI[list_] := Sort[Reap[Sow @@@ list, _, List][[2]]]
```

Then,

```
iI[l]

{{a, {x}}, {b, {x}}, {c, {x, y}}, {d, {y}}, {e, {y}}, {h, {x}}}
```

and

```
In[22]:= 
words=DictionaryLookup[];
abWords=DictionaryLookup["ab"~~___];
l={#,RandomChoice[abWords,RandomInteger[{1,30}]]}&/@words[[1;;3000]];
First@Timing@iI[l]
Out[25]= 0.047
```

**EDIT**

Here is an alternative version with a similar (slightly worse) performance:

```
iIAlt[list_] :=
   Sort@Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 2]], #[[All, All, 1]]}] &@
           GatherBy[Flatten[Thread /@ list, 1], Last];
```

It is interesting that `Reap` - `Sow` here gives an even slightly faster solution than the one based on structural operations.

**EDIT 2**

Just for an illustration - for those who prefer rule-based solutions, here is one based on a combination of `Dispatch` and `ReplaceList`:

```
iIAlt1[list_] :=
   With[{disp = Dispatch@Flatten[Thread[Rule[#2, #]] & @@@ list]},
       Map[{#, ReplaceList[#, disp]} &, Union @@ list[[All, 2]]]]
```

It is about 2-3 times slower than the other two, though.

Comment: Nice indeed. `Thread`-ing the list isn't even necessary; you could do something like `iI[list_] := Sort[Reap[Sow @@@ list, _, List][[2]]]` to make it even faster.

Comment: @Heike Indeed, thanks. When I was developing code, I somehow first thought that it should be `Sow[#2,#1]&`, which, if true, required `Thread`. When I realized the ordering is direct, I forgot to remove it. Will edit to use your version.

Comment: @belisarius Can't wait :). I shouldn't keep you alone in that scary place :) I added another version. b.t.w.

Comment: @belisarius actually, 2 steps to glory :) One answer is the toolbag CW one. It's only gonna take Leonid longer if he keeps deleting his answers ;)